# How to create new column in excel sheet with corresponding values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet

[image]

and another like this

[image]

I want to add the aisle_id in the first sheet according to the product_id like this

[image]

I need help for doing this preferably using python dataframes or sql server

Comment: No image, add text data

Comment: In Sheet 1 Product_IDs are 5 digits value but in Sheet 2, smaller values are they in continuation or different sets!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas read_excel module as follows:
I have removed the 'aisle_id' column in the first DataFrame as it was not defined and would have lead to a conflict.

```
import pandas as pd

input_file1 = 'sales_table.xlsx'
input_file2 = 'sales_table2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(input_file1)
df1 = df1[['order_id', 'product_id', 'add_to_cart_order', 'reordered']]
df2 = pd.read_excel(input_file2)

pd.merge(df1, df2)
```

This will create a new DataFrame merged on common column by default.

Comment: Thank you! that did the job

Comment: great. vote it up! mark it as the correct answer. @MuhammadAmmar